# How to Normalize Values in a Column of a GeoDataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, normalization, sklearn-pandas, geopandas

There are two shapefiles read in as GeoDataFrames. For one column in each gdf, I need to normalize the values to fall between 0 and 1.

I have tried using the `scaler.fit_transform` function to normalize the values but an error was thrown regarding having passed in a 2D array as opposed to a 1D array. So I then began trying (unsuccessfully) to reshape (using `np.reshape`) the column into a 1D DataFrame before normalizing.

```
    output = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\mrich\OneDrive\GMU\Summer 2019 Comp Migration\output_3_simOutput.shp")
    val = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\mrich\OneDrive\GMU\CSS 645 (Spring 2019)\Final Project\Other_geo_data\gadm36_TUR_1_val.shp")

    # Reshape attributes
    output.simEnd = np.reshape(output.simEnd, (928, -1)
    val.val_mar19 = np.reshape(val.val_mar19, (928, -1)

    # Normalize both actual and predicted REFPOP
    scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
    scaled_actual = scaler.fit_transform(val.val_mar19)
    scaled_predicted = scaler.fit_transform(output.simEnd)
```

The two columns to be normalized are simEnd (in output) and val_mar19 (in val). There are 928 entries in each. I believe they may be GeoSeries.

In the reshaping lines, `Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`.

Another error but cannot tell if is related: `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape.'`

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to help more specifically without a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but if I'm understanding correctly, this appears to be a simple `pandas` question:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':np.random.rand(20) // .01})
df['x_norm'] = (df['x'] - df['x'].min()) / (df['x'].max() - df['x'].min())
```

returns

```py
       x    x_norm
0   38.0  0.426966
1   77.0  0.865169
2   61.0  0.685393
3   48.0  0.539326
4   88.0  0.988764
5   74.0  0.831461
6   49.0  0.550562
7    0.0  0.000000
8   47.0  0.528090
9   60.0  0.674157
10  22.0  0.247191
11  74.0  0.831461
12  34.0  0.382022
13  48.0  0.539326
14  69.0  0.775281
15   3.0  0.033708
16  89.0  1.000000
17  83.0  0.932584
18  57.0  0.640449
19  26.0  0.292135
```